# Javascript/Jquery trying to apply .html within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I explained the Title right, however I'm still quite new to Javascript.

I am trying to output a live calculation in a form using jQuery. I think I have it working using the following:

```
$("#w_amount").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')
        var totalcost= 11 * $(this).val() 
    $(".total_cost").html(totalcost);
})
```

and

```
<input id=\"w_amount\" type='text' class='l' style='width: 100px; text-align: center;' value=''>
<br><br>PlayCoins: <span class=\"total_cost\"></span>
```

So the calculation appears in span class=\"total_cost\"

the problem is I'm trying to apply this in a 'content:' section of an already existing function as seen below:

```
var converting;
function convert() {
  converting=false;
  $.msgBox({
    title:"Convert Funds",
    content:"<div id=\"_withdraw_content\"><br><small>Amount of Doge to convert:</small><br><br><input id=\"w_amount\" type='text' class='l' style='width: 100px; text-align: center;' value=''><br><br>PlayCoins: <span class=\"total_cost\"></span><br></div>",
    type:"info",
    opacity:0.8,
    buttons: [{ value: "Withdraw" }, { value: "Cancel" }],
    success: function(button) {
      if (button=="Withdraw" && withdrawing==false) {
        w_amount=$("input#w_amount").val();
        w_valid=$("input#w_valid_ltc").val();
        if (w_amount!='' && w_valid!='') {
          $("#_withdraw_content").html('<div style=\"height: 50px;\"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="content/images/ajax_loader.gif">');
          withdrawing=true;
          _requestWithdraw(w_amount,w_valid);
        }
        else {
          alert('One of required fields stayed empty!');
        }
      }
    }
  });      
  return false;
```

If someone could tell me where to place the code so that it works I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have slashes in your HTML (e.g. `id=\"w_amount\"`)?

Comment: I'm confused by your overall setup.  Could you  not compute the total cost part of the function before you use the .msgBox and content?

Comment: @j08691I didn't write this particular piece of code but I presume it's because if I didn't add them the '"' symbol/mark would represent the end of the content field - as it, itself begins with ".

Comment: @camdixon Well the total cost part of the function requires information from the content i.e. The input from the #w_amount text field and it's then got to set the span id 'total_cost' to that variable. I am just struggling to know where I need to put the javascript code, to get the two to link with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your elements are added dynamically you'll need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to listen for events on those elements with `$(document).on('keyup', '#w_amount', function(){ // your code here.....});`

---

The slashes in your html are due to the html string being created incorrectly. When generating html in javascript, make sure to wrap your strings in single quotes `'like this'`. That way when you want to write properties in your html like `'<input class="myclass"'`, you dont have to escape the `"` characters. Otherwise you end up with `"<input class="myclass""` which isnt valid javascript unless you escape the quotes with slashes.

See, this line of code uses double quotes to wrap the string so it has the slashes to escape the inside quotation marks:

`content:"<div id=\"_withdraw_content\"><br><small>Amount of Doge to convert:</small><br><br><input id=\"w_amount\" type='text' class='l' style='width: 100px; text-align: center;' value=''><br><br>PlayCoins: <span class=\"total_cost\"></span><br></div>"`

Notice though, that this line actually uses single quotes to wrap the string. Because it does, you dont need the slashes to to escape the quotation marks and infact, the slashes are simply read as part of the string and outputted in your html.

`$("#_withdraw_content").html('<div style=\"height: 50px;\"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="content/images/ajax_loader.gif">');`

---

You'll also need to get rid of all those slashes in your html.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#w_amount', function(){
   // alert('pressed')
    var totalcost= 11 * $(this).val() 
    $("#total_cost").html(totalcost);
})



var converting;
function convert() {
  converting=false;
  $.msgBox({
    title:"Convert Funds",
    content:'<div id="_withdraw_content"><br><small>Amount of Doge to convert:</small><br><br><input id="w_amount" type="text" class="l" style="width: 100px; text-align: center;" value=""><br><br>PlayCoins: <span id="total_cost"></span><br></div>',
    type:"info",
    opacity:0.8,
    buttons: [{ value: "Withdraw" }, { value: "Cancel" }],
    success: function(button) {
      if (button=="Withdraw" && withdrawing==false) {
        w_amount=$("input#w_amount").val();
        w_valid=$("input#w_valid_ltc").val();
        if (w_amount!='' && w_valid!='') {
          $("#_withdraw_content").html('<div style="height: 50px;"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="content/images/ajax_loader.gif">');
          withdrawing=true;
          _requestWithdraw(w_amount,w_valid);
        }
        else {
          alert('One of required fields stayed empty!');
        }
      }
    }
  });      
  return false;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="w_amount" type="text" class="l" style="width: 100px; text-align: center;" value="">
<br><br>PlayCoins: <span id="total_cost"></span>
```

Comment: I didn't write this particular piece of code but I presume the quotations i.e. " would represent the end of the content field. As it, itself begins with a quotation i.e. ". When I remove them it just errors. Will try implementing your example though with the slashes still there.

Comment: You're welcome, I also edited the above to show you how to get rid of the slashes